# Proving an integral is 0

Tags: integration

> Let $f : [1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $f$ is Reimann
>   integrable in $[1,a)$ $\forall a $ and $\int_1^\infty f(t)\mathrm{d}t$
>   converges absolutely.
>
> Show that
>
> $$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty } \int_1^\infty f(t)\sin(\alpha t)\mathrm{d}t = 0$$

Consider the integral $$I(a,\alpha) = \int_1^a f(t)e^{i\alpha t}\mathrm{dt}$$

Then integrating by parts,

$$I = \left[\frac{f(t)e^{i\alpha t}}{i\alpha}\right]_1^a - \int_1^a \frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{i\alpha}f'(t)dt$$

Then $$|I| \le \left|\left[\frac{f(t)e^{i\alpha t}}{i\alpha}\right]_1^a\right|+\left|\int_1^a \frac{e^{i\alpha t}}{i\alpha}f'(t)dt\right|$$

$$\le \left|\frac{f(a)}{\alpha}\right| +\left|\frac{f(1)}{\alpha}\right| + \frac{1}{|\alpha|} \int_1^a |f'(t)|dt$$

$$\le \frac{1}{|\alpha|}\left[\cdots\right]$$

where the terms in the the brackets are bounded, and so $$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty} I(a,\alpha) = 0$$ which proves that 
$$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty } \int_1^\infty f(t)\sin(\alpha t)\mathrm{d}t = 0$$ and 
$$\lim_{\alpha \to \infty } \int_1^\infty f(t)\cos(\alpha t)\mathrm{d}t = 0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Interesting approach but, how you knows that $\int_1^\infty|f'|<\infty$?

Comment: @Masacroso because $\int_1^a f' = f(a)-f(1) $? I am exchanging the order of the limits here. I haven't been able to justify going from $\int f'$ to $\int |f'|$ though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of this approach is that the derivative may not exist. And even if it exists, this one may be not integrable.

Using the convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty}\left|f(t)\right|\mathrm dt$, it suffices to prove that for any $R$, 
$$\tag{*}   \lim_{\alpha\to\infty}\int_1^Rf(t)\sin\left(\alpha t\right)\mathrm dt=0.$$
To this aim, fix a positive $\varepsilon$. There are two step functions $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ such that for all $t\in[1,R]$, $\varphi(t)\leqslant f(t)\leqslant \Phi(t)$ and $\int_1^R\left(\Phi(t)-\varphi(t)\right)\mathrm dt\lt\varepsilon$. In this way, we can prove (by the triangle inequality) that for all $\alpha$, 
$$\left|\int_1^R\Phi(t)\sin(\alpha t)\mathrm dt-\int_1^Rf(t)\sin(\alpha t)\mathrm dt\right|\lt\varepsilon.$$
It thus suffices to prove (*) when $f$ is a step function.

Comment: This was the approach I was going to suggest. +1!